# can't set TTY resolution in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, grub2, virtualbox, display-resolution, tty

**Ubuntu server 16.04 installed on a virtualbox vm - no Xorg.**
Trying to change resolution same way as with previous ubuntu versions.
in /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=keep
```

ran

```
update-grub
```

as root and rebooted - resolution works during grub menu but as boot continues it reverts to 800x600.

I have tried manually setting the grub_gfxpayload value, using keep, using a different resolution, all do the same thing and **ONLY on the 16.04 vm** that i have. I have a 14.10 vm and these settings work fine (all of them, actually).

Also tried vga= (which is deprecated), tried using uvesafb which doesn't launch (modprobe doesn't start it correctly and thus the second step of the answer mentioning it doesn't work), and vesafb which gives me the following error:

```
modprobe FATAL: vesafb not found in /lib/modules/(kernel name)/
```

I'm wondering if this is an issue with VMs specifically, since I can do this part on my standard computer, which is also running 16.04. Perhaps the drivers for Virtualbox cause the framebuffer to not start properly? Not sure why it'd only be on 16.04 and not previous versions, though.

Comment: It seems you looked at the top two answers of the linked question at best. Please try *all* answers that appear viable to your situation and include the results in your question. Thanks.

Comment: ... no, i tried all of them.

Comment: Again, what *exactly* did you try and what happened?

Comment: edited - also if there's an Q with 5+ answers and 90% of them either don't work for the situation mentioned (and my question is v. specific, rather than a general 'how do i change console res') or in the case of the last one, aren't even relevant to resolution changing then MAYBE it's not an *exact* duplicate. In this case 100% of the answers don't work so it's, perhaps, even more likely that it's not.

Comment: For reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/893350/ubuntu-16-04-2-tty-resolution-cannot-be-re-set 
Much more likely to be same issue. 0 answers

Comment: I'm not asking you to show the results of all the different variations of the answers. You can lump similar ones together. Look at it from a the point of view of somebody who tries to help and answer your question: how are they going to understand the situation on your system if they don't know how or why it differs from the system of most people in the relevant areas. If you show what you did and what happened there's a good chance that a relevant difference will show up and a reader may notice that.

Comment: ok ok, edited question to hopefully be more clear and less combative. It's just very frustrating, I've been knocking my head against repeatedly for a few days with no headway or even a decent lead on why the system is behaving like this